Curve Group ID from Curve to Points: How to preserve separate splines in Geometry Node?
First time working with Geometry Nodes. I'm trying to manipulate control points on a curve. I have a curve with two splines. Once I modify the point positions (not shown here; assume there's lots of missing nodes operating on the points), how can I get the correct Curve Index to feed to Points to Curves: Curve Group ID, so that I get two curves back out?

Two separated Bezier splines in a single curve object...

...become a single curve after the Geometry Node is done
Test file for your ease


Edit: this gives me a point cloud with 12 of the same points, all at the same position. Gaaahh!


Option 1: Don't Convert to Points
As pointed out by Gordon Brinkmann, if you can modify the geometry without ever leaving the original curve, your sub-splines will stay intact. This is probably what you want. (It's what I wanted.) Here the Set Position node is used directly on the curve geometry to offset every control point by an amount based on the index:

Option 2: Capture Spline Index Before Making Points
Using Capture Attribute on the curve geometry before using Curve to Points preserves the index of the spline (not the points of the curve) which you can then feed to Points to Curves > Curve Group ID:

Note that (for reasons I'm too young to understand) the Index cannot be used with Transform Geometry node:

...but you can use it with Set Position, at least. Again, note how the captured Index here is the index of the spline (0 or 1), but then once used by Set Position it is the index of the point within the point cloud.


You are kidding me, aren't you? Your "Option 1" is just what I told you in my answer. And sorry I did not answer earlier, but where I live it was night and I had to sleep. As I understood all you wrote so far, you want to project the points onto the surface - which can be done with my answer (your option 1), I just did not show that because your question asked about how to avoid the curve becoming a single spline, so that's what I concentrated on. But now that I'm back from the dead I edited my answer to give you the full monty, separate splines, projected onto a surface with a Raycast node.

By the way, the Index cannot be used for the Transform Geometry node because other than the Set Position node it is not affecting the points of a geometry individually, only the geometry as a whole. So it cannot take multiple transformations for multiple points, only one transformation for all of them.

@GordonBrinkmann I am not kidding you. :) You are absolutely right that option 1 is what you led me to understand. I've edited the answer to give you credit. However, even though my question turned out to be an XY situation, my question title and prose explicitly mention "Curve Group ID", which your answer did not address. I feel this is important to address in the accepted answer, for others finding this answer via Google and looking for something slightly different. Hence my Option 2.

Sure, you explicitly mention the Curve Group ID but as you said yourself, it was an XY problem and so I intentionally ignored it - because in the original question you seemingly asked for the group ID only as a matter of getting back the original splines. Which is absolutely not necessary. Sorry I did not keep up with all your changes from just wanting to keep separate splines to having this group ID at all costs...

Sorry if I am missing some important point in your setup, but if you want to keep the splines separate, why do you convert the Curve to Points and then back with Points to Curve? Just plug the Group Input directly into the Curve to Mesh node and the splines stay separated:

If your curve does not have enough points for your liking, that's where the Resample Curve node comes into play. It resamples your curve with one of the three methods to choose from: Count, Length and Evaluated.
In the following examples I've instanced icospheres on the points to show the results.
When you use Count (which is the default option), each spline will have the given number of points from start to finish at even distances, here it's 20:

While this seems okay, the problem is the count will stay the same on each spline, no matter how long or short it is. So if there is a quite short third spline, the point distribution looks very different to the others:

This is where the option Length comes in handy. You set a distance (on spline, not in 3D space) which you want to have between the points.
Note that this will not be the exact distance between the points, as the Resample Curve node tries to distribute them evenly. The start and end point of a spline are fixed and will not be changed. So Blender calculates how many points can be placed inbetween over the length of the spline and space them evenly (so the final distance between the points is less or equal than the given distance). More about this in my answer to this question: Resample Curve Node , length precision

The last method Evaluated has no other settings in the node. It uses the Resolution which is given in the Object Data Properties which depend on the geometry of the curve and so the distances of evaluated points can vary between the original control points.
Your curve object has a Resolution of 54, that is of course very high (which good for a smooth curve in both the previous methods) and looks a bit "crowded" in this case:

But turning it down to 8 shows the effect quite good. The Resolution of the curve is the number of segments between the control points of the curve:

Now if you want to use a Raycast node to project the curve onto the surface, just do that. In the example below I used the Is Hit output for the Selection in the Set Position, otherwise the two points to the right which are not above the surface would give a bad result and be projected to the origin:

In this example you can also see that one problem is, between two points a segment is straight. Which means, if two points are for example on opposite sides of a peak, the curve goes through it. What can help in this case is resampling the curve with much shorter distance (I decided to use the Length option set to 0.005 m, as shown above because this method will give most even results on all spline lengths). If you do not instance icospheres on it, it will be okay:

Of course you never mentioned instancing icospheres, these were just my visualization of the points. But in case you wanted them there, instead of having hundreds of them overlapping, the trick now is double resampling: after the high resolution curve is projected onto the surface, you resample the curve with a lower resolution just for the icosphere instances. So the projected curve is resampled with a length of 0.005 m and for the instances I resample it with a length of 0.1 m:

Instead of double resampling you could also do something like taking the high resolution curve and only instancing on the n-th point by using the index etc. but depending on resolution there is always a risk that there are no instances on start and/or end points of the splines etc. so I think resampling is the better way.
With the high resolution curve this also works on a smooth surface. I have also given the curve a slight offset upwards so that it is less sunken into the surface.


I oversimplified. I sample/separate and then create because my end goal is to adjust the points. You’ve made some nice visualizations here, but you’re not recreating a curve object at the end. My hangup is understanding how to capture the “Curve Index” (should be “Spline Index” IMHO) so I can feed it into “Curve Group ID” to create separate splines in the output curve.

@Phrogz I'm not creating a curve object? You don't create a curve object with your Curve to Mesh node. The output of a Resample Curve node is a curve object (it literally says "Curve" on the output socket). The instanced icospheres are just to visualize where the curve points are - that's nothing you have to do for your curve, I could just have plugged the resampled curve into the Curve to Mesh node instead. And if you want to keep it a curve, then don't plug it into a Curve to Mesh node. Simple as that.

Sorry, let me try to be more clear. My goal is to take a curve with N splines, get points along them all (original control points or resampled, I don't care), modify those points (e.g. drop them varying distances along Z), and then create a new curve object where the points are separated by spline they came from. Curve with Splines -> Points -> Curve with Splines is my trouble. I don't know how to ~capture the Curve Index attribute to feed an appropriate value into Curve Group ID on Points to Curves.

@Phrogz I guess I have to be more clear: all further processing is not really relevant - if you do not need separate points explicitly, you can do all of this with the original splines if they have the points you need and they have the benefit of already being separated into the original splines. I have edited my answer again and added projecting the points down onto the surface with a Raycast node. The only reason I can see to separate the splines into points and then back to splines would be if you want to reassemble them differently - but then capturing the Group ID would make no sense.
